# "Complete" a set algorithmically efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, set, big-o

I have this little toy problem that is bothering me. I think it is equivalent to any number of equivalent problems of more seriousness.  No, this is not a homework or interview question... although possibly I will use it to interview people at some point if I feel like I know a provably optimal solution.

I learned the word *supervocalic* (an adjective describing a word or phrase containing each of the five vowels—A, E, I, O and U—exactly once).  Examples are 'question mark`, 'ambidextrous', and of course 'supervocalic'.

I wrote a small Python program to identify the supervocalic *words*.  This was easy enough, and the heart of it is:

```
matches = {}
for w in words:
    pat = tuple(w.count(v) for v in vowels)
    if pat in matches:
        matches[pat].add(w)
    else:
        matches[pat] = {w}
```

`words` is simply from a large wordlist I have (the SOWPODS Scrabble dictionary, with about 270k words.  I can identify the supervocalic words simply with `matches[(1,1,1,1,1)]` ... i.e. what are the words with exactly one of each vowel.  FWIW, `vowels` is technically configurable here, so my small script could do the equivalent thing for any subset of the characters (and any wordlist).

My problem is that I'd like to find all the **ngrams** that are supervocalic.  The words are 1-grams.  What 2-grams, 3-grams, etc. that also make supervocalic phrases.  It turns out that I have 175 words with no AEIOU; so technically every element of the powerset of those can be appended to every ngram that does not include them.  That's a lot.

But ignoring those 2^175 extra variations of every "filled" supervocalic phrase, how do I combine the count tuples.  There are lots of equivalent words in terms of vowel counts, so of course that's lots of combination, e.g.:

```
pat: (1, 0, 1, 0, 0); numwords: 5499
pat: (0, 1, 0, 1, 1); numwords: 2703
```

So taking any one from the first listed group and any other from the second listed group qualifies.  That's 14,863,797 2-grams right there.  Actually, twice that many since either order is fine.

Let us also assume I have thrown out every pattern with any element more than one, which would be words that cannot be included in any supervocalic phrase because they are too "vowel rich" all on their own.

I can see by eyeball that `(1, 0, 1, 0, 0)` and `(0, 1, 0, 1, 1)` are complementary patterns that together will "fill" the vowel space (or whatever space of elements in a general version of the problem).  For arbitrary tuples of any length, how do I find all N-sized collections of tuples that will combine as "filled tuples" (but not as overfilled ones)?

In essence, despite the lead-up, that's my problem to find these complementary N-sized collections of tuples... in the most efficient manner possible for arbitrary tuple lengths, not only length 5. Even though I prefer Python and my short code snippet is that, the question should apply to pretty much any programming language.

Comment: For arbitrary tuple lengths, determining the existence of even one valid collection of tuples is NP-hard. This can be shown by reduction from the [exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover), among other ways. Counting all of them is probably ♯P-hard.

Comment: I've sort of stipulated that the tuple of all 1s exists in the problem description.  So that would be O(1) to prove existence since it is in the problem.  But it's easy to suppose I didn't stipulate so.

Still, I think the description is more supposing that **all** n-tuples of elements in {0,1} exist, so it's not proving valid collections, but finding them... which indeed might be #P-hard.

Comment: But thank you, by the way! I did not know the name for my problem, which indeed really is the Exact Cover Problem.

Comment: If all tuples exist, then that actually puts a pretty low bound on the tuple length, rendering the problem tractable to approaches that would be infeasible with longer tuples.

Comment: Why does the existence of all tuples put a low bound? There need not be any particular storage space associated with the collection of tuples of the form `(a_0 ... a_n) | a ∈ {0,1})`.  We can generate them as needed rather than store them in actual memory.

Is there in fact a simpler algorithmic approach if we know we can generate any tuple as part of an exact cover? It's not obvious to me there is, but also not obvious there is not.

Comment: If your input is in the form of tuples, or counts of tuples, then the fact that there is a nonzero count for every possible tuple means that the length of the tuples grows with the logarithm of the length of the input.